# resizing box when zooming in or out

Tags: html, css

I have problem with resizing of "button" when i scroll the page out, it reizes on it's own, and I'm wondering if there is any way to prevent it from happening, to stay the same when it is when I resize it :

[image]

[image]

#### My CSS :

```
#regsubmit {
    src: url('../fonts/Arial.otf');
    border: none;
    background-color:#7C8E46;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0.5% 11px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 12px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-appearance: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem could be in

```
padding: 0.5% 11px;
```

The first value is in percentage rate. That's why it is always calculated relatively.
Try to set

```
padding: 5px 11px; //or another fixed value you would like to have
```

And see if it is what you are looking for.